# setMinutes + getMinutes no me traen el resultado esperado

Tags: javascript, jquery

qué tal. Estoy intentando crear una condición donde el usuario puede acceder a su turno con hasta 20 minutos de tolerancia.
El problema es que cuando le sumo 20 minutos a los minutos de la hora actual (obtenida mediante ***new Date()***), me tira un resultado como este: "**11:1654178525529**" en el *alert(hora_final)*.

Voy a compartir el código de la hora de cómo lo estoy creando.

```
let fecha_actual = new Date();
hora = fecha_actual.getHours();
minuto = fecha_actual.setMinutes(fecha_actual.getMinutes() + 20);

let hora_final = hora + ":" + minuto;

alert(hora_final);
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Lo dejare como comentario porque no sabria dar una buena explicacion de como usar Date(). Esto deberia servir en tu caso 
    let fecha_actual = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20 * 60000);
Te recomiendo usar alguna libreria como moment.js

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente. Si, conozco moment.js, gracias por tu sugerencia, la voy a tener en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```js
let fecha_actual = new Date().getTime();
const cant_minutos = 20;
const hora_final = new Date(fecha_actual + (cant_minutos * 60 * 1000));

console.log(hora_final.getHours() + ':' + hora_final.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'))
```

Espero que te sirva. Abrazo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola German, muchas gracias. Voy a tenerlo en cuenta y voy a probarlo :).
 Un abrazo y agradezco tu ayuda, por lo visto este respeta de manera correcta los dos dígitos de los minutos!

Answer (score 0):

La solución del problema me la brindó Ignacio a través de un comentario a mi pregunta.
Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
let fecha_actual = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20 * 60000);
    hora = fecha_actual.getHours();
    minuto = fecha_actual.getMinutes();

    let hora_final = hora + ":" + minuto;

alert(hora_final);
</script>
```

Modifiqué el valor fecha_actual, creé una fecha y dentro de ella utilicé "getTime()". La función terminará sumando 20 minutos a la fecha actual.